# Stripe-React: wrapping root application with Elements Provider

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am working on building out a react front end with a node backend using stripe for payments. The [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button) mentions that: *To use Element components, wrap the root of your React app in an Elements provider*.

It displays the App as being wrapped in the Element's provider. Does this mean that the structure of a react project should always be one where the App.js component is wrapped in an Elements provider?

Or can that Elements provider be wrapped around any component that will have elements displayed on it?

Example below:

Documentation has this example where a checkoutform is in the App component:

```
...
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_51HhkvNBmZZhLkiuRzN5UwsSHQQbK9y1CALJpr3l23aT7bauIx1JzCdkKlVx26FrtFkFE8QtAUZctcuUtBhRxcqti00grkBypzH",
  {apiVersion: "2020-08-27"});

function App() {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <CheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  );
};
```

But what if I use my `App.js` purely for routing and `CheckoutForm` is rendered in a different page like `Profile`. Is it recommended then that `Elements` should go in the Profile component as opposed to being wrapped in App.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it recommended then that Elements should go in the Profile
> component as opposed to being wrapped in App.js?

Yes, it's perfectly fine to wrap only the components that require Stripe.js (via the [useElements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#useelements-hook) and [useStripe](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#usestripe-hook) hooks) in the Elements Provider. In other words, any component that uses `useElements` or `useStripe` needs to either itself by wrapped by the Elements Provider or have an ancestor somewhere up the component tree that's wrapped by the Elements Provider.

In your example I would personally go with wrapping the `Profile` component with Elements if that's the only component that uses Stripe. Under the hood the Stripe Elements provider uses the Context API, which you can read more on here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html