# Stripe Elements: Despite wrapping whole component, I get:Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of your app that calls useStripe()

Tags: stripe-payments

The following code works fine on localhost. It's just that Vercel's CI/CD throws this error in compilation

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/billing/CheckoutForm". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of your app that calls useStripe() in an <Elements> provider.
```

As [this other Stack Overflow question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865267/stripe-react-wrapping-root-application-with-elements-provider), I need to wrap the whole CheckoutComponent inside the Element component, which I am already doing. Like this:

index.js

```
<Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
   <CheckoutForm />
</Elements>
```

CheckoutForm.js

```
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
```

I also tried wrapping the ancestors of CheckoutForm with the Elements component, but it doesn't solve the problem and it also messes up the behavior

This is how my entire CheckoutForm file looks like. Very standard to the Stripe docs

```
const CheckoutForm = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // We don't want to let default form submission happen here,
    // which would refresh the page.
    event.preventDefault();

    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      //`Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: "https://example.com/order/123/complete",
      },
    });

    if (error) {
      // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
      // confirming the payment. Show error to your customer (for example, payment
      // details incomplete)
      setErrorMessage(error.message);
    } 
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <PaymentElement />
      <br />
      <div className="d-flex flex-items-center flex-justify-center">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" id="checkout-and-portal-button" type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
          Purchase
        </button>
      </div>
      {errorMessage && <div>{errorMessage}</div>}
    </form>
  );
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

And this is how the return statement of my index.js file looks like. Perhaps the only "weird thing" I'm doing is the conditional rendering of Elements based on the retrieval of the client secret

```
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr))",
      }}
    >
      <div className="d-flex flex-items-center flex-justify-center flex-column">
        <div
          className="Box d-flex flex-items-center flex-justify-center flex-column p-4 p-6 m-6"
          style={{ maxWidth: "80ch" }}
        >
          <h1 className="h3 mb-3 f4 text-normal">
            Purchase your Watermelon subscription
          </h1>
          {/* render if component already mounted */}
          {retrievedClientSecret && (
            <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
              <CheckoutForm />
            </Elements>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: The code you shared looks correct. What I think is happening is Vercel is for some reason trying to pre-render the component `CheckoutForm` by itself. That's not really possible, so you get an error message. To fix this you need to disable pre-rendering for that component. Check [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error) and [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16124) for pointers on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this!

As @soma suggested, the code was correct but Vercel was trying to render the CheckoutForm component by itself. Without the stripePromise and options being fully set after fetching the clientSecret, this would not be possible. We depend on those props to render the component.

So the solution was lazy loading the CheckoutForm component and disabling server side rendering. Using [Next JS' dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) like this:

CheckoutForm.js

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const CheckoutForm = () => {
...
// component here
...


// export default CheckoutForm; This is the regular way of exporting a component
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(CheckoutForm), {
  ssr: false
})
```

Comment: You should just move the `CheckoutForm` (component) file from your `/pages` directory and into a `/components` directory.

Answer (score 0):

> [T]he only "weird thing" I'm doing is the conditional rendering of
> Elements based on the retrieval of the client secret

Ah, that might be it, React hooks are not friendly to conditionally applying, they must return always the same amount of hooks. Try wrapping the `Elements` in a Fragment or a div.